# Transform one list into another

Tags: algorithm

Given two lists, for example:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]
```

I wish to find a series of moves which will transform list a into list b, where each move is an operation:

```
move(from_index, to_index)
```

which moves the element at location from_index and places it at location to_index. So if:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

then the operation move(3,1) on the list a will transform a into:

```
a = [0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Is the transformation always possible?

Comment: is this Python?

Comment: Are these lists permutations of each other?

Comment: Are you looking for something more specific like the minimum number of moves?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. The problem is language agnostic, and I'm not looking for a minimal solution, although a minimal solution would be a bonus. I think a solution is always possible, although I do not have a proof. And yes, the end result is always a permutation of the start position, since it is obtained from it after a series of moves.

Comment: So basically you want [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is a variation of the insertion sort if you take list b as the sorted sequence.

Answer (score 1):

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]

move(0, 8)
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 9]

move(0, 8)
a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 8, 9]

move(1, 8)
a = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 8, 9]

move(2, 8)
a = [2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]

a==b

Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Basically, start with the left- most element and move it to where it should be. For example, I took 0 and placed it right after the value that it is supposed to eventually end up behind, which is 7. I continued moving from left to right until all of the elements were in the desired order.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a general algorithm, not the specific moves to this one case.

Comment: @MarkMeyer good point. I just added a summary of my general strategy to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works well. Can you optimize it so it is optimal or nearly optimal? For example, this algorithm would take 5 moves to transform [0,1,2,3,4,5] -> [5,0,1,2,3,4], when one move is sufficient (move(5,0)).

Answer (score 1):

I'd iterate over the second sequence (the sorted list) and swap items in the first. I wrote this pseudo-code in python:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> b = [2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]
>>> def swap(seq, i, j):
...     a = seq[i]
...     seq[i] = seq[j]
...     seq[j] = a
...
>>> for index_in_b, value in enumerate(b):
...     index_in_a = a.index(value)
...     if index_in_b != index_in_a:
...         swap(a, index_in_a, index_in_b)
...         print('move {} to {}'.format(index_in_a, index_in_b))

move 0 to 2
move 1 to 4
move 2 to 6
move 3 to 7
move 4 to 6
move 5 to 6
move 6 to 7
```

In this case I'm moving the items in the first sequence by swapping them.

#### Update

We can slightly improve the performance in python by removing the move inside swap function and also removing the function call. Here is a performance comparison:

```
import timeit
s1 = """
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]
def swap(seq, i, j):
    a = seq[i]
    seq[i] = seq[j]
    seq[j] = a

for index_in_b, value in enumerate(b):
    index_in_a = a.index(value)
    if index_in_b != index_in_a:
        swap(a, index_in_a, index_in_b)"""

s2 = """
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]
for index_in_b, value in enumerate(b):
    index_in_a = a.index(value)
    if index_in_b != index_in_a:
        a[index_in_a], a[index_in_b] = a[index_in_b], a[index_in_a]"""


# on an i7 macbook pro
timeit.timeit(s1) 
4.087386846542358
timeit.timeit(s2)
3.5381240844726562
```

Slightly better, but for sure there are better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, although converting a swap operation into two move operations is going to be too expensive.

Comment: We can make it slightly faster by moving both at one go. I'll update the answer with timeit results.